# Difference between "class << anObject" and anObject.class_eval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I see the following code in the attribute_fu plugin:

```
module AttributeFu
    module Associations #:nodoc:                                                                                                                                                
        def self.included(base) #:nodoc:                                                                                                                                          
            base.class_eval do
                extend ClassMethods
                class << self; alias_method_chain :has_many, :association_option; end

                class_inheritable_accessor  :managed_association_attributes
                write_inheritable_attribute :managed_association_attributes, []

                after_update :save_managed_associations
            end
        end

        ...
    end
end
```

When I try to replace

```
class << self; alias_method_chain :has_many, :association_option; end
```

with:
     alias_method_chain :has_many, :association_option?

I get the following error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method': undefined method `has_many' for class `ActiveRecord::Base' (NameError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method_chain'
        from /home/twong/git/physpace/vendor/plugins/attribute_fu/lib/attribute_fu/associations.rb:9:in `included'
```

I thought those two lines would do the same thing, but it looks like I'm wrong.  Can somebody explain my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# init.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval { include AttributeFu::Associations }

module AttributeFu
    module Associations
        def self.included(base)
            # base == ActiveRecord::Base (the class)
            base.class_eval do
                # class_eval makes self == ActiveRecord::Base, and makes def define instance methods.
                extend ClassMethods

                # If has_many were an instance method, we could do this
                #   alias_method_chain :has_many, :association_option; end
                # but it's a class method, so we have to do the alias_method_chain on
                # the meta-class for ActiveRecord::Base, which is what class << self does.
                class << self; alias_method_chain :has_many, :association_option; end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Another way to play around with this is to put this into IRB:

```
class A ; end
A.class_eval { puts self.inspect ; class << self ; puts self.inspect ; end }
```

See also

- [class_eval vs. instance_eval in Classes](http://briancarper.net/2007/06/19/class_eval-vs-instance_eval-in-classes/)
- [instance_eval method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000336)
- [class_eval method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001673)

Answer (score 0):

In that case, `self` does not mean the anObject, it's more a sugar construct.

```
class << self
  ...
end
```

defines class methods for the enclosing object. The method `alias_method_chain` is a method, that alias things. In that case, it aliases `has_many` to `has_many_without_association_options` and `has_many_with_association_options` with `has_many`. In your case it alias class methods, so, you have to use it in the class method scope. It allows extending methods without much hassle.

Class methods are called like, say :

```
SomeThing.bar_method
```

whereas instance methods are called on instances of class :

```
assoc = SomeThing.new
assoc.foo_method
```

The corresponding code would be :

```
class SomeThing
  def foo_method
    ...
  end
  class << self
    def bar_method
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

in your case, you have the module `AttributeFu::Associations`. When included in class Foo, it runs Foo.class_eval, which defines some instance attributes inside Foo, and launches a method, `alias_method_chain` inside the class methods scope (`class << self`).

There also is an `extends ClassMethods` which must define either :

```
def self.has_many_with_association_options
    ...
end
```

or

```
class << self
  def has_many_with_association_options
    ...
  end
end
```